# How to define a host group on Nagios 4

Tags: configuration, nagios

I would like to define a host group on Nagios 4. In recon it should be defined somewhere in `/usr/local/nagios/etc`. I tried creating a file `hostgroups.cfg` that with contents:

```
define hostgroup{
   hostgroup_name   webservers
   members          *
}
```

Is this the right place to add that configuration?
(I'm a Nagios-newbie)

Comment: Well, did you try it? Did it work? You'll also need to inform Nagios to read your hostgroups.cfg file.

Comment: I tried it, but nagios doesn't seem to pick up that file. How do inform Nagios to read it?

Comment: Look at the nagios config file.

Answer (score 5):

In your nagios.cfg file, you can add a line pointing to the hostgroups.cfg file you created, thus telling nagios to include that file.

```
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hostgroups.cfg
```

You can also specify a directory, and nagios will process any of the files found within:

```
cfg_dir=/usr/local/nagios/etc/directory_containing_cfg_files
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put in the host group entry into my hosts.cfg file.  Once Nagios was checked for errors and restarted, my host groups were there and available.  I didn't have to edit the nagios.cfg file this way, either.  It just works.  Using Nagios Core 4 (4.4.1)